# MySql - rank, given player's rank and around

Tags: mysql

I need to get top players, the rank of a given player as well as few players which have ranks around that given player.

To explain more clearly, the bellow table is what I want to have, it shows top 3 players by scores, the rank of the given player (id=11) and 2 players who have scores just above and bellow that given player:

```
+----+------+-------+--------+------+
| id | name | score | @rk:=0 | rank |
+----+------+-------+--------+------+
|  7 | g    |    31 |      0 |    1 |
|  8 | h    |    29 |      0 |    2 |
|  9 | i    |    28 |      0 |    3 |
|  4 | d    |    23 |      0 |    8 |
| 11 | k    |    21 |      0 |    9 |
|  1 | a    |    20 |      0 |   10 |
+----+------+-------+--------+------+
```

The sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(20),
score int
);

INSERT INTO test (name,score) VALUES ("a", 20),("b", 19),("c", 23),("d", 23),
("e", 27),("f", 25),("g", 31),("h", 29),("i", 28),("j", 24),("k", 21);
```

I have managed to display rank, top players, given player:

```
SELECT id,name,score,rank FROM
(SELECT *,@rk:=@rk+1 AS rank FROM test, (SELECT @rk:=0) r WHERE 1 ORDER BY score DESC) AS s
WHERE rank<=3 OR id=11 ORDER BY rank ASC
```

The result:

```
+----+------+-------+------+
| id | name | score | rank |
+----+------+-------+------+
|  7 | g    |    31 |    1 |
|  8 | h    |    29 |    2 |
|  9 | i    |    28 |    3 |
| 11 | k    |    21 |    9 |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

I am stuck to display players who have scores around (just above or below id=4 and id=1) the given player.

I prefer to 1 sql query, considering performance since the data may be large.

Comment: Mysql is bad at these type of queries, do it in your application

Comment: according to your provided data set id 4,3 both has a score of 23 so what is the criteria to select only id 4 why not both 3 and 4? [sample demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1e18/1)

Comment: I think it is pretty complicated to do. I just tried to split the ranking part off into a view, but MySQL doesn't allow variables in view definitions.

Comment: Thanks all. To M Khalid: any criteria / way for ranking same scores are good for me

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my problem. To find around score players, I try to query (the middle part - s2 and s3) the rank of the given player first, store in varian @givenrank. The mysql query is the following:

```
SELECT id,name,rank FROM
(SELECT *,@rk:=@rk+1 AS rank FROM test, (SELECT @rk:=0) r WHERE 1 ORDER BY score DESC) AS s,

(SELECT @givenrank:=rank2 FROM
(SELECT *,@rk2:=@rk2+1 AS rank2 FROM test, (SELECT @rk2:=0) r2 ORDER BY score DESC) AS s2
WHERE id=11) AS s3

WHERE rank<=3 OR (@givenrank-1<=rank AND rank<=@givenrank+1) OR id=11 ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

The result is exactly what I want:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | name | rank |
+----+------+------+
|  7 | g    |    1 |
|  8 | h    |    2 |
|  9 | i    |    3 |
|  4 | d    |    8 |
| 11 | k    |    9 |
|  1 | a    |   10 |
+----+------+------+
```

Some new issues:

- Look like the query has to process same data for few times (s, s2, s3 are quite similar). Any idea to optimise / speed up them?
- The query works well if the data has a record of the given user. If not, instead of returning the list of top players only (as I expected), it returns empty result (since s3 is null). To check it, just replace all id=11 to id=111.

To solve the second issue, I have separated the query into two as the bellow. The rank varian is queried first and won't effect the result in case of being null. It works well for both cases (the given player has or does not have a record in the table). However, using two queries is not the solution I like (I prefer 1 query only). Any idea to improve it?

```
SELECT @givenrank:=rank2 FROM
(SELECT *,@rk2:=@rk2+1 AS rank2 FROM test, (SELECT @rk2:=0) r2 ORDER BY score DESC) AS s2
WHERE id=11;

SELECT  id,name,rank FROM
(SELECT *,@rk:=@rk+1 AS rank FROM test, (SELECT @rk:=0) r WHERE 1 ORDER BY score DESC) AS s
WHERE rank<=3 OR (@givenrank IS NOT NULL AND @givenrank-1<=rank AND rank<=@givenrank+1) OR id=11 ORDER BY rank ASC;
```